# Can't get the token from paypal payment speckPaypal zf2

Tags: php, paypal, zend-framework2

i'm trying to use the module speckpaypal for zf2 , but can't get the token , here is my code :

```
    public function passTransactionAction(){

        $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
        $paypalConfig = new \SpeckPaypal\Element\Config($config);

        //Then, set up http client using curl libraries provided by Zf2:

        $client = new \Zend\Http\Client;
        $client->setMethod('POST');
        $client->setAdapter(new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl);
        $paypalRequest = new \SpeckPaypal\Service\Request;
        $paypalRequest->setClient($client);
        $paypalRequest->setConfig($paypalConfig);


        $paymentDetails = new \SpeckPaypal\Element\PaymentDetails(array(
                'amt' => '20.00'
            ));
        $express = new \SpeckPaypal\Request\SetExpressCheckout(array('paymentDetails' => $paymentDetails));
        $express->setReturnUrl('http://project.local/return');
        $express->setCancelUrl('http://project.local/cancel');
        $response = $paypalRequest->send($express);

        echo $response->isSuccess();

        $token = $response->getToken();
        echo "---------------------- token : $token----------------------";
$this->redirect()->toUrl('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$token);

    }
```

i had set the params in the config file ( a test account sandbox.paypal ), and when showing the $response value , i get this :

```
SpeckPaypal\Response\Response Object ( [_rawResponse:protected] => [_success:protected] => [_errors:protected] => Array ( [0] => ACK key not found in response. [1] => Configuration is not valid. ) [_response:protected] => [_multiFieldMap:protected] => Array ( [ERRORS] => Array ( [0] => LONGMESSAGE [1] => SEVERITYCODE [2] => SHORTMESSAGE [3] => ERRORCODE ) [FILTERS] => Array ( [0] => FMFfilterID [1] => FMFfilterNAME ) [ITEMS] => Array ( [0] => NAME [1] => DESC [2] => AMT [3] => NUMBER [4] => QTY [5] => TAXAMT [6] => ITEMWEIGHTVALUE [7] => ITEMWEIGHTUNIT [8] => ITEMLENGTHVALUE [9] => ITEMLENGTHUNIT [10] => ITEMWIDTHVALUE [11] => ITEMWIDTHUNIT [12] => ITEMHEIGHTVALUE [13] => ITEMHEIGHTUNIT [14] => ITEMCATEGORY ) ) )
```

Any idea from where comes the bug ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the correct way to implement SpeckPaypal ZF2 for ExpressCheckOut , i followed this tuto : 
http://phpcantho24h.blogspot.com/2014/04/paypal-express-checkout-creating-simple.html

```
 // fonction permettant de generer le paypal request : 
    protected function getPaypalRequest() {
        // recuperer la configuration du speckPaypal ( depuis son fichier de configuration speck-paypal.local.php dans config/autoload/ )
        $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
        $paypalConfig = new \SpeckPaypal\Element\Config(
                $config['speck-paypal-api']);

        $adapter = new \Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl();
        $adapter->setOptions(array('curloptions' => array(
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            )
        ));

        $client = new \Zend\Http\Client;
        $client->setMethod('POST');
        $client->setAdapter($adapter);

        $paypalRequest = new \SpeckPaypal\Service\Request;
        $paypalRequest->setClient($client);
        $paypalRequest->setConfig($paypalConfig);

        return $paypalRequest;
    }

    //Fonction qui va envoyer les informations de payment et rediriger le client vers PayPal Express Checkout:
    public function paypalExpressCheckoutAction() {

        // recuperer les infos depuis le form :
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $montant = $request->getPost('montant');
        $paypalRequest = $this->getPaypalRequest();
        $fk_annonceur = $request->getPost('annonceur');

        // preparer le paymentDetails :
        $paymentDetails = new \SpeckPaypal\Element\PaymentDetails(array('amt' => $montant));
        $express = new \SpeckPaypal\Request\SetExpressCheckout(array('paymentDetails' => $paymentDetails));

        // définir les liens de retour en cas de Success ( ReturnUrl ) et de Annulation (CancelUrl )
        $express->setReturnUrl('/application/client/paymentConfirmh');
        $express->setCancelUrl('/application/client/paymentCancel');

        // Envoyer les infos à PayPal
        $response = $paypalRequest->send($express);
        // Récuperer le token generé :
        $token = $response->getToken();

        // Créer une variable session contenant les infos utiles ( à utiliser plus tard dans la fonction de confirm de payment )  :
        $paypalSession = new \Zend\Session\Container('paypal');
        $paypalSession->tokenId = $token;
        $paypalSession->montant = $montant;
        $paypalSession->client= $client;

        // Return le lien pour rediriger l'utilisateur vers Paypal Express Checkout :
        $this->redirect()->toUrl('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . $token);

    }

    // fonction en cas de success de payment from Express Checkout , recuperer les infos from Paypal , enregistrer les données dans prepaiement :
    public function paymentConfirmAction() {

        $this->layout('layout/anlayout');
        // Recuperer payment information depuis PayPal:
        // Recuperer Payer Information depuis PayPal
        $paypalSession = new \Zend\Session\Container('paypal');
        $paypalRequest = $this->getPaypalRequest();

        $expressCheckoutInfo = new \SpeckPaypal\Request\ GetExpressCheckoutDetails();
        $expressCheckoutInfo->setToken($paypalSession->tokenId);
        $response = $paypalRequest->send($expressCheckoutInfo);


        $montant = $paypalSession->montant;
        $paymentDetails = new \SpeckPaypal\Element\PaymentDetails(array('amt' => $montant));

        $token = $response->getToken();
        $payerId = $response->getPayerId();

        $captureExpress = new \SpeckPaypal\Request\ DoExpressCheckoutPayment(
                array(
            'token' => $token, 'payerId' => $payerId, 'paymentDetails' => $paymentDetails
        ));
        $confirmPaymentResponse = $paypalRequest->send($captureExpress);
        // Enregistrer le prepaiement :
                   $prepaiementObject = new \Application\Entity\Prepaiement();
        $prepaiementObject->setClient($client);
        $prepaiementObject->setPaymentamount($montant);
        $prepaiementObject->setPaymentapi('Paypal');
        $prepaiementObject->setPaymentdate(new \DateTime("now"));
        $prepaiementObject->setCorrelatinid($response->getCorrelationId());
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($prepaiementObject);
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();


        // recuperer les infos de payer :
        /* $first_name = $response->getFirstName();
          $last_name = $response->getLastName();
          $ship_to_street = $response->getShipToStreet();
          $ship_to_city = $response->getShipToCity();
          $ship_to_state = $response->getShipToState();
          $ship_to_zip = $response->getShipToZip();
          $email = $response->getEmail();*/

    }

    // Fonction pour traiter payment en cas d'annulation depuis Express Checkout :
    public function paymentCancelAction() {
        $this->layout('layout/anlayout');
        $paypalSession = new \Zend\Session\Container('paypal');
        $view = new ViewModel();
        return $view;
    }
```

Hope it helps.